# Traductor Java Español -> Inglés

Tags: java

Quiero realizar un programa que lea una frase en español y la traduzca al
inglés (y al revés), pero no sé como seguirlo...

Comment: Amigo, para un traductor necesitas implementar diccionarios y algoritmos y de cierta manera, no es nada sencillo de explicar. Es además una pregunta demasiado abierta dado que existen múltiples métodos y si te ayuda, mas sencillo es implementar un plugin, ahora si es algo básico, debes ocupar diccionarios que almacenen las palabras según esté conjugado tu verbo en español.

Answer (score 5):

Creo que usando un mapa para este caso sería más lógico. El código resultante quedaría:

```
    Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
    Map<String, String> diccionario = new HashMap<String, String>();
    diccionario.put("yo", "me");
    diccionario.put("tu", "you");
    diccionario.put("el", "he");
    diccionario.put("ella", "she");
    // ...y cuantas palabras quieras

    // Esto realiza la "inversión" del diccionario
    Map<String, String> dictionary = new HashMap<>();
    for (String key : diccionario.keySet()) {
        dictionary.put(diccionario.get(key), key);
    }

    String frase = teclado.next().toLowerCase().trim();
    teclado.close();

    StringBuilder phrase = new StringBuilder();
    // Separamos las palabras por espacio e iteramos sobre cada una de ellas
    for (String palabra : frase.split(" ")) {
        // buscamos en el mapa
        // dependiendo del idioma, buscaríamos en diccionario o dictionary
        String word = diccionario.get(palabra);
        // Si no existe, dejamos en Español
        if (word == null) {
            word = palabra;
        }
        // "concatenamos"
        if (phrase.length() != 0) {
            phrase.append(" ");
        }
        phrase.append(word);
    }
    System.out.println(phrase.toString());
```

Answer (score 2):

Siguiendo después de `ingles[9] = "spanish";`

```
   System.out.println("Idioma para traducir Español o Inglés");
   String idiomaa = teclado.next();     // idioma = inglés

   String [] traductor;
   String [] idioma;

   if ("Español".equals(idiomaa)){
     traductor = español; // tu array de esp
     idioma = ingles;
   }else {
     traductor = ingles; // tu array de ing
     idioma = español;
   } 

    System.out.println("Introduce una palabra: ");
    frase = teclado.next();
    // frase  =  tu
    for(int i = 0 ; i < idioma.length; i ++){
       // i = 0 ---> yo
       // i = 1 ---> tu
       if(frase.equals(idioma[i])){ // encuentra el tu
             System.out.println("Traducido: " + traductor[i]); // Accedes a la posición
             break;
        }
    }
```

Aquí lo que vamos hacer es simplemente cuando encuentre la palabra en el idioma que van a escribir, cogemos la posición en la que estamos y accedemos a la posición del otro array.

Si quieres traducir FRASES, tienes que hacerlo **guiándote por los espacios**, aquí ya tienes una idea de como empezar para las palabras.

Comment: La variable idioma está repetida, una vez es un String y otra un array de Strings.

Comment: Ya está corregido.

Comment: La primera variable idioma tiene dos a, está como `idiomaa`.

Comment: precisamente por eso son variables distintas :), no es lo mismo String idiomaa que String [] idioma

Answer (score 0):

No se el contexto en el que quieres usar esto, si es como ejercicio para aprender a volcar datos y compararlos, o para realmente hacer un traductor. 
Debes pensar que una traducción literal no es acertada en la mayoría de los casos.
El verbo "play" en inglés, puede ser usado para jugar o para tocar un instrumento por ejemplo, donde en muchísimos casos es más cosa de contexto que de traducción literal. Entonces es algo más complejo que esto.
De igual manera, pongo un ejemplo de lo que pides.
En mi caso he usado un array bidimensional simulando una posible tabla de base de datos, donde me he imaginado que cada fila es una palabra y cada columna (cada array) una traducción de un idioma diferente.

```
  public void traducir(){
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> idiomas = new ArrayList<>();
    idiomas.add(new ArrayList<>());
    idiomas.add(new ArrayList<>());
    idiomas.get(0).add("yo");
    idiomas.get(0).add("tu");
    idiomas.get(0).add("el");
    idiomas.get(0).add("juegas");

    idiomas.get(1).add("I");
    idiomas.get(1).add("you");
    idiomas.get(1).add("he");
    idiomas.get(1).add("play");



    String fraseEnEsp = "tu juegas";
    String[] palabaras = fraseEnEsp.split(" ");
    StringBuilder frase = new StringBuilder();
    for(String palabra : palabaras){
        int indiceDePalabra = idiomas.get(0).lastIndexOf(palabra);
        String palabraEnIngles = idiomas.get(1).get(indiceDePalabra);
        frase.append(palabraEnIngles + " ");
    }

    System.out.println( frase);

}
```